# Real projects on .Net Core

Tags: .net-core

I need to write essay about `.Net Core` and about real projects written on it.
But i can not find any examples of such projects.
Can you tell me some examples of real `.Net Core` projects?

Or they do not exist yet?

Comment: We don't track everybody in the world who uses .NET Core, sorry.

Comment: Look here - http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/projects, from a quick look at `Cake` that seems to be built on .Net Core.

Comment: Quite a few here https://www.microsoft.com/net/customers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst I agree that this is not the correct forum for such a question, a quick and simple Google search suggests that https://www.ageofascent.com/ is built on .Net Core to some degree.

Additionally, although not quite what you're looking for, .Net Core is supported in lots of Windows Docker containers running Windows Server Core, due to it's lightweight nature.

A bit of research goes a long way. Good luck with the essay.